# Alien fails on rpm, Install Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: rpm, alien

I'm trying to install Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
 So far, everything looks good until it comes to the alien command to get .deb out of the .rpm.

```
root@Borderline-Central:~/maya2017Install# alien -c *.rpm
sh: 1: rpm: not found
Error executing "LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME}'adlmapps12-12.0.32-0.x86_64.rpm'":  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 489.

root@Borderline-Central:~# apt install rpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
rpm is already the newest version (4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@Borderline-Central:~# rpm
The program 'rpm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install rpm
```

If I try

```
for i in *.rpm; do sudo alien -cv $i; done
```

Same problem with rpm not found.

I've tried to purge rpm, installed it again. It doesn't help at all

---

I've started with Ubuntu a month ago so I'm new and I think I'm missing something.

`rpm` is installed but can't be found somehow.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

---

It's not a duplicate question, I've done the installation similar to the description in the link to GitHub. But my problem is that `rpm` isn't found even if it's said `rpm` is already the newest version. So still the question. How can I fix the missing rpm problem!?

---

As requested the output of `which rpm` and `ls -l /usr/bin/rpm`

```
hethu@Borderline-Central:~$ which rpm  
/usr/bin/rpm  

hethu@Borderline-Central:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/rpm  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15208 Jan 19  2016 /usr/bin/rpm
```

Comment: Why are you running as root?

Comment: I've tried it with the sudo command... and I had the same issue. So, I had the idea running sudo -i and do the whole process again in another directory.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `which rpm` and `ls -l /usr/bin/rpm`? Thanks.

Comment: Well, thanks to David Foerster... At least one who've seen that it isn't a duplicate question. Did the other guys just read the title? I couldn't get a solution to the missing rpm file yet... Maybe someone of those who voted for a duplicate question can show me where the solution is about my problem... But I think this can be closed and deleted... thanks...

Comment: @Hethu Completely same problem, did you solve it and if so how did?

Comment: @Hethu it is not a duplicate question, a thumbs up from me :)

Comment: I solved it, sudo apt install rpm --reinstall